# Strip HTML from text but also specific content wrapped in html in Java

Tags: java, html

Let's say I have the following text:

```
<blockquote>
  <div>This is text and html in a blockquote<\/div>
  More text in a block quote.
<\/blockquote> 
Here's some content <b> bolded </b> and <i> other random HTML tags </i>
```

I'd like to strip the entire blockquote out, and keep the content in other html tags. So the output would be:

```
Here's some bolded and other random HTML tags.
```

I know theres a hundred or more answers to "Stripping HTML from content" but I can't find an answer on stripping HTML tags but also content that is wrapped specific html tags.

How can I get the desire output in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It may seem like an overhead but you could use Jsoup to [parse the HTML](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-) and operate with the [Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html).
Maybe there is something more lightweight for your problem but Jsoup should to the job just fine. You can [select elements by using css selectors](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-), [remove unneeded](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove--) and [get the plain text (without tags)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#text--) out of them.

Here is a simple sample:

```
final String html = "<html><div><bq>i do not want this</bq>but this <b>should</b> all <i>get</i> read</div></html>";
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
final Elements div = document.select("div");
div.select("bq").remove();
System.out.println(div.text()); // prints but this should all get read
```

Comment: In example would be nice. I'm looking into this and I can select tags but not the content within tags too?

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple regex expressions: `.replaceAll("<blockquote>.*</blockquote>", "").replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "")`. It should be enough.

Comment: What if blockquotes has attributes and such?

Comment: @kinx Just drop the closing angle bracket from the opening blockquote elemnt.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JSoup in this way:

```
String text = "<blockquote>\n" +
            "  <div>This is text and html in a blockquote</div>\n" +
            "  More text in a block quote.\n" +
            "</blockquote> \n" +
            "Here's some content <b> bolded </b> and <i> other random HTML tags </i>";
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
    String cleanStr = Jsoup.clean(text, whitelist);
```